# Javascript and Jquery loop array in Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone explain the following to me please.

Case 1:

```
function MyObj () {

    this.myArray = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i<5; i++){
        this.myArray.push(i);
        console.log("add to array:" + i);
    }
}
```

which works as I expected. this.myArray has 0,1,2,3,4.

Case 2:

```
function MyObj () {

    this.myArray = new Array();

    $.each([0,1,2,3,4],function(i,v){   
        this.myArray.push(i);
        console.log("add to array:" + v);
    });
}
```

I got complains from Firebug "this.myArray is undefined."

Thanks.

Comment: That's because of the scope. "this" in case 2 is the actual number in the array. It's referencing [0,1,2,3,4]. You just need to create a var and don't use 'this'. So you can do something like `function(){   
        myArray.push(this);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second example, you're passing a function to `$.each`, which means that `$.each` will invoke that function. Therefore, inside that function, `this` will refer to what `$.each` assigns it to be.

Normally, it would be a reference to `$.each` in itself, but jQuery invokes the callbacks using `.call` which allows manual specification of the context to use. In the case of `$.each`, `this` is set to always refer to the current object of the iteration.

There are ways to work around this, you could for instance do something like this:

```
var context = this;
$.each([0,1,2,3,4],function(i,v){   
    context.myArray.push(i);
    console.log("add to array:" + v);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. Is there a way that I can push the values into myArray in case 2?

Answer (score 0):

`this` in JavaScript is "bound" to current object. In first example it's global scope, in second function argument (I mean 0, 1 and so on), where myArray isn't defined. Read [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) and [this explanation](http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/).

In your case you can do:

```
function MyObj () {

    this.myArray = new Array();
    var that = this;

    $.each([0,1,2,3,4], function(i,v){   
        this.myArray.push(i);
        console.log("add to array:" + v);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not in the correct scope for the `MyObj()` function, which instead refers to the current iteration of the `$.each()` loop. Do instead:

```
function MyObj() {

    var $this = this;
    this.myArray = new Array();

    $.each([0,1,2,3,4],function(i,v){   
        $this.myArray.push(i);
        console.log("add to array:" + v);
    });
    console.log(this.myArray);
}
MyObj();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KmxJC/

Answer (score 0):

In the .each function, `this` refers to the element under inspection, thus the actual 0,1,2...etc. Moreover, the `this` will always be an Object, even if the original is a number (in your case) or a string or anything else.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ for more info.

edit: I think to solve your problem, you could simply make a variable `arr` which would be accesible from within the .each code. That is, if .each is not in global scope, of which I am not sure.

```
var arr = new Array();

$.each([0,1,2,3,4],function(i,v){   
    arr.push(i);
    console.log("add to array:" + v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you work with jQuery function .each, this means not myObj obj, but element of array. You should use such code.

```
function MyObj () {

this.myArray = new Array();
var obj = this;

$.each([0,1,2,3,4],function(i,v){   
    obj.myArray.push(i);
    console.log("add to array:" + v);
});
}
```